# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: FileReader

Tags: exception, macros, clojure, illegalargumentexception

We are trying to write some Clojure code and we successfully compiled it a couple of minutes ago, but now we get this random exception.

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: FileReader, compiling:(myproject\core.clj:24:17)
```

Here is our code:

```
(ns myproject.core)

(defmacro safe ([bindings & code] form)
 (if (list? bindings)
 `(try 
   ~bindings 
  (catch Throwable except# except#)) 

(if (= (count bindings) 0)
  `(try ~code 
     (catch Throwable except# except#)) 



`(let ~(subvec bindings 0 2)

 (try
   (safe ~(subvec bindings 2) ~@code)
   (catch Throwable except# except#) 

   (finally
     (. ~(bindings 0) close))))))) ;;safe


(def div(safe (/ 12 2)))
(def v (safe [s (FileReader. (java.io.File. "M:/test.txt"))] (. s read)))
```

Answer (score 2):

We found the problem.

We had to import the FileReader from java.

```
(import '(java.io FileReader File))
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the qualified name without importing — like you did with `java.io.File`.